# htaccess ModRewrite URLs to pull contents from Index.php file, leaving URL as is

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to run a mod_rewrite rule to load the contents of index.php regardless of the entered URL.
Then in the index.php file I will deal with either returning a correct page or outputting a 404 page.
This is for SEO purposes to allow a nice URL like:
http://www.example.com/product
rather than
http://www.example.com/?p=product

I have this working on one sub folder of my blog but when trying to test it on a new project all i get is 500 errors as for ALL urls.

Here is the existing htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /products/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.danclarkie.co.uk/products [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://danclarkie.co.uk/products/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Any help ^_^

Dan

Comment: Are you sure that your webserver has mod_rewrite enabled? Also, is the `RewriteBase` correct, shouldn't it be `products` rather than `prodcuts`?

Comment: aside from the typo, which isn't present in the live version :)
mod_rewrite must be enabled because I have the same set up running on another subfolder of my site and it runs perfectly. :S

Comment: your index.php is running fine ? it may be it who is generating the 500 error

Comment: the index.php file isnt causing the problem I don't think, at the moment it contains only this:
`ok`